# WooCommerce Subscription add order note when end date is changed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I try to add an order note on a subscription when the end date is changed. This is my current snippet. It does not add an order note.

I have the info for the values etc. from the official WooCommerce Subscription page: [https://woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/functions/#:~:text=To%20get%20the%20end%20date,%3Eget_time(%20'end'%20)%3B](https://woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/functions/#:%7E:text=To%20get%20the%20end%20date,%3Eget_time(%20%27end%27%20)%3B)

```
function add_subscription_note_when_end_date_change($subscription_id){
    $subscription = wc_get_order($subscription_id);
    $old_end_date = substr($end[0],0,10);

    if($_POST['end'] !==null && $old_end_date !== $_POST['end']){
        $note = 'End date changed from '.$old_end_date. ' to ' .$_POST['end'];
        $subscription->add_order_note($note);
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta','add_subscription_note_when_end_date_change',0);
```

Comment: The code is working and adding notes to the subscription. But there is warning undefined variable `$end`

Comment: Thanks. But where is this undefined variable? Whats wrong with the snippet? :)

Comment: `$old_end_date = substr($end[0],0,10);` $end is not defined in the above line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function add_subscription_note_when_end_date_change( $subscription_id ) {
        
    // Get the  end date of the subscription
    $old_end_date = $subscription->get_date('end');
    $old_end_date_ymd = explode(' ', $old_end_date);
    $old_end_date_yr = $old_end_date_ymd[0];

    $submited_end_date = sanitize_text_field(wp_unslash($_POST['end']));

    if (null !== $submited_end_date && $old_end_date_yr !== $submited_end_date) {

        $note = 'End date changed from ' . $old_end_date . ' to ' . $submited_end_date;
        $subscription->add_order_note($note);
    }
 }
    
 add_action('woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'add_subscription_note_when_end_date_change', 0);
```

Comment: Works! Thanks. But is always add a note also when the end date is not changed when a subscription is saved. But why? there is a check for date.

Comment: Please echo both the `$old_end_date` and   `$submited_end_date` if it's changing.

Comment: It echos already both values. The problem is that when I change for example the address and save, then it also adds a order note with the enddate. But there was no change for end date.

Comment: Are they both printing the same value, and still the code entered inside the if statement.?

Comment: No they print not the same value. The date format looks not as we want it currently yyyy-dd-mm and we would like to have dd-mm-yyyy. But this is not the main problem. The problem is that always a note is added also when we don't change the end date.

Comment: Thanks. But we have fatal errors. But not related to your change. The problem is actually that when that snippet is active, that we can not change the order status of a order. We get the following fatal error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\Overrides\Order::get_date()

Comment: I'm not able to find the problem here. The get_date function seems ok for me. Why there is a problem to change a order status? The code is related to subscription and not orders.

Comment: Just add 'is subscription object' check wrapping the whole code